# Edit black space on Github Pages dinky theme

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I made a website using GitHub pages and chose this theme called "Dinky Theme"

https://github.com/pages-themes/dinky

I like the layout and color but when I finished building the website, there was too many black space on the both end (left & right).

Is there any way I could edit it so that there is less space on both left and right?

thank you

Comment: What do you mean with space on left and right? Can you show us an example in your website?

Comment: @DiogoRocha This is the example website provided by developer. https://pages-themes.github.io/dinky/ And there is blank space on the right side. I want to get rid of it